# Proof that for subsets $A$ and $B$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ that $(A \cap B)^{\circ} = A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Where the circle is the interior of the set. It seems quite trivial but I cannot find a direct proof for this: $(A \cap B)^{\circ} = A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$. Would this also imply that $A^{\circ} \cup B^{\circ} \subseteq (A \cup B)^{\circ}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- For any *open* set $U$ we have that $$U \subseteq A \text{ implies }U \subseteq A^\circ$$
  (this is because $A^\circ$ is equal to the union of all the open sets contained in $A$).
- $(\subseteq)$ Observe that $(A \cap B)^\circ \subseteq A \cap B \subseteq A$.
- $(\supseteq)$ Observe that $A^\circ \cap B^\circ \subseteq A^\circ \subseteq A$.
- Finally $A^\circ \subseteq A$, so $A^{\circ} \cup B^{\circ} \subseteq A \cup B$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

$R^{\circ}$ can be looked at as the greatest open subset of $R$: every open subset of $R$ is a subset of $R^{\circ}$ and as a union of these open subsets  $R^{\circ}$ itself is an open subset of $R$.

This makes clear that $R\subseteq S\implies R^{\circ}\subseteq S^{\circ}$.

We have $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$ so $\left(A\cap B\right)^{\circ}\subseteq A^{\circ}$
and $\left(A\cap B\right)^{\circ}\subseteq B^{\circ}$.

Then $\left(A\cap B\right)^{\circ}\subseteq A^{\circ}\cap B^{\circ}$.

Using the same sort of arguments you can deduce $A^{\circ} \cup B^{\circ} \subseteq (A \cup B)^{\circ}$

Comment: What a nice answer you have there ^^

Comment: @dtldarek Thank you, I am flattered.